# Uniform random bit from a mask

Tags: random, rust, statistics, bit-manipulation

Suppose I have a 64 bit unsigned integer (u64) `mask`, with one or more bits set.

I want to select one of the set bits uniformly at random from `m` to give a new mask `x` such that `x & mask` has one bit set. Some pseudocode that does this might be:

```
def uniform_random_bit_from_mask(mask):
  assert mask > 0
  set_indices = get_set_indices(mask)
  random_index = uniform_random_choice(set_indices)
  new_mask = set_bit(random_index, 0)
  return new_mask
```

However I need to do this as fast as possible (code similar to the above in a low-level language is slowing a hot loop). Does anyone have a more efficient scheme?

Comment: If you can get only the [number of set bits efficiently](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive), then you wouldn't have to creating a list of indices.

Comment: Yep, getting the number of set bits is cheaper - but I still need to set the bit in the final mask, so I need the indexes?

Comment: Random function should just tell you to flip the ith bit, so you don't actually need to keep track of the list, but I believe you will still have to iterate through the bits. However, isn't the `rand()` function the real bottleneck here?

Comment: Don't have the profile in front of me, but yes rand() is the majority of the bottleneck. Irrc the rest of the current code is deeply sub-optimal though, and I think it might be possible to do something clever.

Comment: Perhaps you can state the actual problem if you believe it can be optimized. Right now I would say these optimizations would give you less than 1% improvements in speed (although profiling would give you exact values).

Comment: What does this question have to do with Rust? The code example looks like python.

Comment: @hellow I assume the OP wants an answer in Rust and the Pythonish pseudocode is only meant to be illustrative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The details how to optimize this depend on several factors you did not specify – the target architecture, the expected number of set bits in the mask, the language you want to use, the requirements on the randomness and many more. Without knowing further details, it's hard to give a useful answer, but I'll give a few hints that may prove useful anyway.

Most modern architectures have an instruction to count the number of set bits in an integer, generally called "popcount", and this instruction is exposed in most low-level languages. In Rust, you can use the [`count_ones()` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.u64.html#method.count_ones). This gives you the total number `k` of bits to select from.

You can then generate a random number `i` between `0` and `k - 1` (inclusive). The next step is to select the `i`th set bit in `mask`. An efficient approach to do so is this loop (Rust code):

```
for _ in 0..i {
    mask &= mask - 1;
}
let new_mask = 1 << mask.trailing_zeros();
```

The loop clears the least significant set bit in each iteration. Since `i < k`, we know that `mask` can't be zero after the loop. The last line generates a new mask from the least significant bit of `mask` that is still set.

On common architectures, it is likely that the bottleneck will be the random number generator. If you are using Rust's `rand` crate, you can use [`SmallRng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.1/rand/rngs/struct.SmallRng.html) for improved performance, at the cost of being cryptographically insecure, which may not be relevant for your use case.

Comment: How did you come up with `mask &= mask - 1`? Have you seen something similar before or did it just come to you? I always forget that you can do clever bit tricks with arithmetic operators too

Comment: @trentcl I've seen that before, a long time ago, but I can't remember where I picked it up. It's useful surprisingly often. :)